# CSS Transitions swap function

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am using CSS transitions to make a slide out panel. I am using Javascript to fire to animation like so;

```
function slidein()
    {
    document.getElementById('container').className = 'slidein';
    }

    function slideout()
    {
    document.getElementById('container').className = 'slideout';
    }

<div onclick="slideout()">Click</div>
```

What I need to know is once I have fired the first function how can I swap the function so the user can then close the panel.

Comment: give the div a data-* attribute that tells you if the panel is out or in at the moment. Use only one function on click. depending on the data-* attribute value you choose then the new class of the element and change the attribute value.

Comment: I'm sorry but my javascript isn't very good would you be able to give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var slideState = 'slidein';

function slide() {
    if ( slideState == 'slidein' ) slideout();
    else slidein();
}

function slidein() {
    document.getElementById('container').className = 'slidein';
    slideState = 'slidein';
}

function slideout() {
    document.getElementById('container').className = 'slideout';
    slideState = 'slideout';
}

<div onclick="slide()">Click</div>
```

Comment: I cant get this to work. Here is a link to the page I am working on http://boxseven.co.uk/test/index.html